# highlighting/unhighlighting cells and dependents when they are changed/unchanged

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types

My ultimate goal is to highlight cells when they are different than when the spreadsheet was opened. This includes cells that the user edits directly, as well as cells that change because they are dependent on the cell that the user changes. If the user changes the cell back to the original value, I want to highlighting to disappear.

My approach was to write a range containing the cells of interest to a global 2d array when the workbook is opened. Then, I wrote a worksheet_change event that compares the changed cell and its dependents with the corresponding value that was stored in the array when the workbook was opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    arr_1 = Sheet26.Range("A1:AR331")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
Dim dep As Range
Dim r As Range


'Check the changed cell to see if it has changed from when the workbook was opened
If Target <> arr_1(Target.Row, Target.Column) Then

    'If cell has changed, mark it red
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    'Check to see if cells that depend on the changed cell have changed
    Set dep = Target.Dependents
    For Each r In dep
    
        'Check to see if the dependent cell(s) is within the print area
        If Not Intersect(r, Range("A1:AR331")) Is Nothing Then
            If r <> arr_1(r.Row, r.Column) Then
                'if cell has changed mark it red
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                
                'if cell hasn't changed unhighlight it
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next r

Else

'If the target cell matches the value stored in the array, unhighlight the cell
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

End If

End Sub
```

My problem is dealing with cells that contain #N/A. When I write the cell to the array it is stored as "". Then when I go to compare the #N/A stored in the cell with the "" stored in the array, I get a type mismatch. Is there a way to get around this? Also, if my over-all approach is not the best way to solve this, I'd welcome an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using Cstr. Don't know why I couldn't get it to work till now.